# How to calculate week over week difference in python without fixed interval functions such as shift?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, timestamp

I know there are a lot of answers/methods to get WoW differences in Python or Pandas Dataframe but I am finding that many of those don't work in edge cases of my data. I have a dataframe with hourly transaction timestamps and hourly sales and I want to calculate WoW differences for each hour and weekday. I have previously done this with a simple self join in SQL but I need to do it in Python. The data could be missing hours and something like shift is not going to be reliable.

Snapshot of dataframe:

```
transaction_time     |   total_sale
2024-01-05 00:00:00  |      3500
2024-01-05 02:00:00  |      4000
.
.
.
2024-01-12 00:00:00  |      3400
2024-01-12 01:00:00  |      3200
2024-01-12 02:00:00  |      4100
.
.
.
2024-01-19 00:00:00  |      5000
2024-01-19 01:00:00  |      4200
```

I'd do something like below in SQL:

```
with
base_tbl AS 
(
select 
   transaction_time,
   total_sale
from table
where transaction_time betwwn <desired timefarame>
)

 select
    t. transaction_time
    , SAFE_SUBTRACT(SAFE_DIVIDE(t. total_sale, c. total_sale), 1) AS wow_percent_change
  FROM
    base_tbl AS t
  FULL OUTER JOIN
    base_tbl AS c
  ON EXTRACT(HOUR FROM t. transaction_time) = EXTRACT(HOUR FROM c. transaction_time)
  AND TIMESTAMP_DIFF(t. transaction_time, c. transaction_time, DAY)=7
```

I have tried a few things that basically look at fixed intervals between rows such as `shift` like `df['wow_change']=df['total_sale'] - df['total_sale'].shift(168)` but it's not a reliable method with my data. Is there a more error-proof method to do this?
My desired output is something like this:

```
transaction_time     |   wow_chane
2024-01-05 00:00:00  |      nan
2024-01-05 02:00:00  |      nan
.
.
.
2024-01-12 00:00:00  |      -100
2024-01-12 01:00:00  |      nan
2024-01-12 02:00:00  |      100
.
.
.
2024-01-19 00:00:00  |      1600
2024-01-19 01:00:00  |      1000
```

Comment: Pandas has join syntax too, including full outer join.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate this using pandas `merge` function to join on dates.

```
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import timedelta 
def calculate_wow(df):
    df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(hour) # Assuming the dataframe has an hour column

    new_df = df.copy() 
    new_df['7days'] = new_df['hour'] + timedelta(days=7)

    final_df = df.merge(new_df, left_on='hour', right_on='7days', how='left')
    final_df['WoW'] = final_df['total_sale_x'] - final_df['total_sale_y']
    final_df = final_df[['hour_x', 'WoW']]

    return final_df
```